# How to avoid n+1 queries in EF Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using EF Core 2.1 preview which was supposed to reduce N+1 queries problem.
I'm trying to make query, that selects Forum Threads with authors of posts:

```
dbContext.ForumThreads
   .Include(t => t.Posts)
   .Take(n)
   .Select(t => new
   {
      t.Id,
      t.Title,
      PostAuhtors = t.Posts.Select(p => p.Author).Take(5)
   }).ToArray();
```

This produces n+1 queries: For each ForumThread it selects post authors

The schema is simple:

```
public class ForumThread 
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public ICollection<ForumPost> Posts {get;set;}
}

public class ForumPost 
{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Author {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that with less queries (only 2), making some of that behavior in memory. Does this code do what you want?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new SampleContext())
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                var result = db.Threads
                    .Include(t => t.Posts)
                    .Take(10)
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        t.Id,
                        t.Title,
                        t.Posts
                        // Do this in memory  
                        //PostAuhtors = t.Posts.Select(p => p.Author).Take(5)
                    }).ToArray();

                Console.WriteLine($"» {result.Count()} Threads.");
                foreach (var thread in result)
                {
                    // HERE !!
                    var PostAuhtors = thread.Posts.Select(p => p.Author).Take(5);
                    Console.WriteLine($"» {thread.Title}:  {string.Join("; ", PostAuhtors)} authors");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SampleContext : DbContext
    {
        public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] {
                new ConsoleLoggerProvider((category, level)
                    => category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
                       && level == LogLevel.Debug, true)
            });

        public DbSet<ForumThread> Threads { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ForumPost> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder  
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
                .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFStart;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }

    public class ForumThread
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ForumPost> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForumPost
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: I don't want to load all post, since it can be megabytes of data

Comment: Then I think for now EFCore doesn’t allow other behavior, but this is being addressed: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4007

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I'm using 2.1 preview final ans still getting N+1 queries

Comment: For what I can see, I think the fault is the `Take(5)` that makes the n+1 queries, without the Take it will produce only 2. ([#9282](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9282#issuecomment-359289292))
Maybe one alternative is to have Where clauses to restrict Post from a Thread? (I know is not the same thing...)

Answer (score 0):

*There are pros and cons of your approach.Let me explain,*

### **Your approach**

Cons => queries n+1 times.

Pros => You requested just 5 Authors of your Posts. (n times).

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t].[Id], [t].[Title] FROM [ForumThreads] AS [t] => 1 time

SELECT TOP(5) [p].[Author] FROM [ForumPosts] AS [p] => n time (n => number of ForumThread)
```

### **Other approach you can choose according to the size of your data in DB.**

```
        var source = dbContext.ForumThreads.Include(t => t.Posts).Take(5).ToList();
        var result = source.Select(t => new { t.Id, t.Title, PostAuhtors = t.Posts.Select(p => p.Author).Take(5).ToList() }).ToArray();
```

Pros => queries 1 time.

Cons => You get all Authors of your Posts from DB, then filter them. (This can be cost too much according to the size of your data).

```
    SELECT [t.Posts].[Id], [t.Posts].[Author], [t.Posts].[Content], [t.Posts].[ForumThreadId] FROM [ForumPosts] AS [t.Posts]
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t0].[Id]
    FROM [ForumThreads] AS [t0] ORDER BY [t0].[Id]
) AS [t1] ON [t.Posts].[ForumThreadId] = [t1].[Id] ORDER BY [t1].[Id]
```