# How to avoid multiple queries one complex objects in EF .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

In .net core 2.2
I have a model likes this:

```
public class A
{
  public ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
  public ICollection<C> C { get; set; }
  public ICollection<D> D { get; set; }
}

public class C
{

}

public class D
{

}
```

And the query is something like this:

```
var query = from record in Set<A>()
            where record.Id == Id
select new AProjection
{
    BProjection =( from bRecord in Set<B>() 
                    where bRecord.Id = record.BId
    select new BProjection 
    {
        CProjection = bRecord.C.Select( b => new CProjection {/* data here */ }),
        DProjection = bRecord.C.Select( b => new DProjection {/* data here */ })
    })
}
```

I want to return the data into a projection, but for each object of Type B is making a query to get the objects Type C and another to get the objects Type D. How can I avoid this behaviour?

It's the  typical N+1 queries problem addressed  in this question:

[How to avoid n+1 queries in EF Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346001/how-to-avoid-n1-queries-in-ef-core-2-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 2.1 has introduced [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries), but as mentioned in the linked documentation, you need to *opt-in* for it by adding `ToList()` to all collection projections.

Also use navigation properties instead of manual joins where possible.

e.g.

```
var query =
    from a in db.Set<A>()
    select new AProjection
    {
        B = (from b in a.B
             select new BProjection
             {
                 C = (from c in b.C select new CProjection { ... }).ToList(), // <--
                 D = (from d in b.D select new DProjection { ... }).ToList(), // <--
             }).ToList() // <--
    };
```

This will execute total 4 SQL queries - one for each projection.